# What is the right method to use Red Hat Software Collections on Amazon AWS EC2 instances?

Tags: amazon-web-services, redhat, licensing

I created a fresh Amazon EC2 instance for testing our software against the Apache 2.4 package from the [Red Hat Software Collections](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Software_Collections/2/html-single/2.2_Release_Notes/index.html). My main motivation was to test on a clean install without the cruft I expect on our local machines.

To install the `httpd24` package one needs to add the `RHSCL` repository via subscription manager. This did no work on the EC2 instance:

```
# subscription-manager repos --enable rhel-server-rhscl-6-rpms
Error: [...] is not a valid repository ID. Use --list option to see valid repositories.
# subscription-manager repos --list
This system has no repositories available through subscriptions.
```

According to the [Red Hat Enterprise Linux on Amazon EC2 FAQ](https://aws.amazon.com/partners/redhat/faqs/) I would have expected the system to be subscribed automatically. Quote (emphasis added):

> Red Hat Enterprise Linux on Amazon EC2 is offered at either a flat, hourly rate with no commitment (On-Demand), or through a one-time, upfront payment (Reserved Instances). **Both purchase options include Amazon EC2 compute charges and Red Hat Enterprise Linux subscription charges.**

Searching the [AWS developer forums](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/) I only found [an answer](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=602647&#602647) saying that one needs an extra license from RedHat (and many other vague answers).

I finally found out that it's sufficient to modify the file `/etc/yum.repos.d/redhat-rhui.repo` like this:

```
[rhui-REGION-rhel-server-rhscl]
name=Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 6 RHSCL (RPMs)
# ...
enabled=1
```

This seems to work but I wonder if this is really the "right way" to do it.

Comment: How did you solve the issue? I've set the flag `enabled` to `1` but still the subscription-manager returns no repos

Comment: I never found a better way. Subscription manager will not list the repositories but yum will install the contained packages just fine.

Answer (score 3):

Ensure the Red Hat Update Infrastructure (RHUI) configuration is up to date:

```
yum update rh-amazon-rhui-client
```

List the available repositories:

```
yum repolist all
```

Find the appropriate repository, and enable it. At the time of writing, the Red Hat Software Collections repository is called `rhel-server-rhui-rhscl-7-rpms`:

```
yum-config-manager --enable rhel-server-rhui-rhscl-7-rpms
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about RHEL6, but on RHEL7 you can use yum-config-manager

`yum-config-manager --enable 'Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 7 RHSCL (RPMs)'`